# What does `a = b()` mean when both `a` and `b` are of class `X`?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm reading an [article on rvalue-references](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_02.html), but I've become confused by the following excerpt:

```
X foo();
X x;
// perhaps use x in various ways
x = foo();
```

Here, X is some user-defined type.

I know that `X foo();` will call X's constructor, and I'm pretty sure `X x;` will not.

However, what does the line `x = foo();` mean? Is there a constructor called? And what would `x = foo;` do?

Try as I might, I couldn't figure out the right words to look up in order to find out what this code means.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `X foo();` is a function declaration.

Comment: You write *"I'm pretty sure X x; will not [call X's constructor]"* Why do you say this?

Comment: I was under that impression, since C++ must provide a method of declaring an object without calling the constructor

Comment: @Mahkoe _"must provide a method of declaring an object without calling the constructor"_ No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know that `X foo();` will call X's constructor

No, it won't. It will declare (but not define) a function named foo, which takes no arguments, and returns an X.

> and I'm pretty sure `X x;` will not.

Yes it will, if it has one. With the above corrections to your understanding, the answer to your question should be evident now, but:

> However, what does the line `x = foo();` mean?

It means call the function foo, and store the result in x.

Comment: Curious... in that case, this leads to two more important questions: what if I want to declare an object of type X and *not* produce a call to the constructor, and how can I tell the difference between `X foo();` being a "prototype for a function returning an X and taking no arguments" and being a "declaration of an object of type X producing a call to its constructor (which doesn't happen to have arguments)"?

Comment: *"what if I want to declare an object of type X and not produce a call to the constructor"* -- You can't. But if you could, that would just be a memory allocation, and there are, of course, a variety of ways to allocate memory in C++.

Comment: *"how can I tell the difference between X foo(); being a "prototype for a function ..." and being a "declaration of an object ..."?"* -- Easy. It's always the former. Never the latter.

Comment: @Mahkoe: You might want to read up on what people call [C++'s "most vexing parse"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Doing some searches for "c++ most vexing parse" will likely be fruitful.

Comment: This "most vexing parse" is very aptly named. Sure caused me a lot of confusion

Comment: @BenjaminLindley aggregate initialization avoids calling the constructor

Comment: @M.M: For types which aggregate initialization avoids calling the constructor, there was no constructor to avoid calling. In that case, `X x;` also avoids calling the constructor.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley there is an implicitly generated constructor,which is called by `X x;` but not by aggregate initialization. This performs default initialization of the class members; see [class.ctor]/5 for detail